# Google code jam: sample contest

Tags: java

here is a link to the google contest that i'm trying to solve
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p0
and i here is below the code that i did.
It works for me so please can someone help me to know if it responds to what is asked?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1692;
    int y = 0;
    int z;
    ArrayList<Character> digit = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] new_digit = {};
    boolean end_loop = true;

    do {
        z = x * y;
        new_digit = ("" + z).toCharArray();
        for (int k = 0; k < new_digit.length; k++) {
            if (!digit.contains(new_digit[k])) {
                digit.add(new_digit[k]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(digit.contains('0'));
        boolean b = true;
        int i = 0;
        do {

            if (!digit.contains((""+i).charAt(0))) {
                b = false;
            }
            i++;
        } while (b == true && (i < 9));
        if (b == true) {
            end_loop = false;
        }
        y = y + 1;
    } while (end_loop == true);
    System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: This question needs more detail. I shouldn't need to visit a external site which at some point might disappear.

Comment: It's a link to google code jam contest so it will not disappear ;)

Comment: The point is that we shouldn't have to go to an external site, we should be able to help with just what is here. Regardless of whether it will disappear or not. And not even Google stuff lasts forever (Google Wave, anyone?).

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  If you have a specific question about a programming problem we can help, but SO is not a tutorial, code-writing or _code-checking_ service.  This question is off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: really sorry :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not specific enough for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your program basically solves the problem except for a limited number of issues:

- You don’t read any input. There is an input format specified.
- Your program sometimes prints `true`, which is not a part of the required output.
- You don’t print in the required output format, `Case #x: y` (for example, `Case #2: 10`).
- You don’t print `INSOMNIA` in the case where Bleatrix counts forever.
- Your program incorrectly includes `0 * N` (that is, 0) in the numbers counted. If I set `x` to 9, expected output is `90`, but you print `45`.
- You don’t check for the digit 9 having been seen. If I set `x` to 10, expected output is 90, you print `80`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback